# Insert the result of a sequence generated with for in a FlexibleXYPlot in clojurescript [SOLVED]

Tags: clojurescript, react-vis

In this question ([How to return two customSVGSeries from a single function in clojurescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438263/how-to-return-two-customsvgseries-from-a-single-function-in-clojurescript/71439062?noredirect=1#comment126378653_71439062)), I learned how to insert the result of a function creating two `customSVGSeries` into an `XYPlot`.

Now I want to insert the result of a `for` calling that same function:

```
(into [:> rvis/FlexibleXYPlot {...}] 
      (doall (for [[id {:keys [x y texto]}] etiquetas]
               (crear-etiqueta id x y texto))))
```

Where `etiquetas` is a map with this form:

```
{:etiqueta-1 {:x 0, :y 0, :texto ["176.6"]}, :etiqueta-2 {:x 1, :y 2, :texto ["Hidrógeno"]}}
```

and `crear-etiqueta` is the function returning two `customSGVSeries`. The problem is that using the code above, nothing is shown in the plot.

I uploaded a repo with a MWE: https://github.com/lopezsolerluis/annie-test-for-stackoverflow

### Edit

I used the excellent idea of Eugene... it works like a charm!

```
     (into [:> rvis/FlexibleXYPlot {...}] 
            (mapcat (fn [[id {:keys [x y texto]}]]
                       (crear-etiqueta id x y texto))
                    etiquetas))
```

Comment: You don't need `doall` because `into` will realize the result of `for`. If `crear-etiqueta` returns a vector of two items but in the end you need a long flat sequence of items, you have to flatten them somehow. One way is to use the same `for` since it can accept multiple collections: `(for [a xs, b a] ...)`. Another way is to use `mapcat` as a transducer and move `crear-etiqueta` there.

Comment: That's great! I would like you have posted it as an answer. :) Anyway, I didn't undestand the first solution (using `for`), and still need to understand the transducer utility. But at least I could have a solution! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment to the question.

Using `for` with two collections:

```
(into [:> rvis/FlexibleXYPlot {...}] 
      (for [[id {:keys [x y texto]}] etiquetas
            series (crear-etiqueta id x y texto)]
        series))
```

`for` will iterate over `eqieuetas` and for each item it will destructure it and pass the result into `crear-etiqueta`, which returns a collection. `for` then iterates over that collection and assigns the value of each item to `series`. Then the body is finally evaluated, which just returns the value of `series`.

Using the `mapcat` transducer:

```
(into [:> rvis/FlexibleXYPlot {...}]
      (mapcat (fn [[id {:keys [x y texto]}]]
                (crear-etiqueta id x y texto)))
      etiquetas)
```

I won't go into the details of how it works - it's all documented [here](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers). I definitely recommend reading that reference in full because of immense usefulness of transducers in many contexts.